# Aplicar estilo css a un solo elemento de layout de Laravel

Tags: css, html5, css3

Cuando aplico este estilo al layout:

```
<!-- Nota: Aqui empieza codigo de menu -->
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
  /* NOTE: The styles were added inline because Prefixfree needs access to your styles and they must be inlined if they are on local disk! */
  @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);


nav {
max-width: 100%;
mask-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0) 0%, #000000 10%, #000000 100%, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0) 90%);
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0px 0;
}

nav ul {
text-align: center;
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2) 25%, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
padding: 24px;
font-family: "Open Sans";
text-transform:uppercase;
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
font-size: 24px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
</STYLE>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<!-- Nota: Aqui termina codigo de menu -->
```

Se aplica no solo al menú de inicio, sino también a la parte del usuario:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Este el código de la parte del usuario la cual quiero separar del estilo que adjunte anteriormente (La que se puede ver en la parte superior en la imagen adjunta)

```
<div id="app">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light navbar-laravel">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li><a href="{{ route('blog') }}">Blog</a></li>    

                </ul>

                <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    @guest
                        <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
                    @else
                    <li><a href="{{ route('tags.index') }}">Etiquetas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ route('categories.index') }}">Categorias</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ route('posts.index') }}">Entradas</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                   onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                 document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                    Logout
                                </a>

                                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                    @csrf
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    @endguest
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

        @if(session('info'))     
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ session('info') }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif

        @if(count($errors))
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach    
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif
</div>
```

La idea es que ese estilo solo se aplique al menú de inicio y no a la parte del usuario.

**EDIT1:** He podido solucionarlo en base a lo que me han dicho.
Este es el codigo del estilo modificado usando clases:

```
<style>
/* NOTE: The styles were added inline because Prefixfree needs access to your styles and they must be inlined if they are on local disk! */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

nav.inicio1 {
max-width: 100%;
mask-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0) 0%, #000000 10%, #000000 100%, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0) 90%);
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0px 0;
}

nav ul.inicio2 {
text-align: center;
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2) 25%, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

nav ul li.inicio3 {
display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a.inicio4 {
padding: 24px;
font-family: "Open Sans";
text-transform:uppercase;
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
font-size: 24px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

nav ul li a:hover.inicio5 {
box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
</style>
```

Y aquí el código de la barra de inicio:

```
<nav class="inicio1 inicio2 inicio3 inicio4 inicio5">
<ul class="inicio2 inicio3 inicio4 inicio5">
<li class="inicio3 inicio4 inicio5">
  <a href="http://localhost:8000/" class="inicio4 inicio5">Inicio</a>
</li>
<li class="inicio3 inicio4 inicio5">
  <a href="{{ route('blog')}}" class="inicio4 inicio5">Actualidad</a>
</li>
<li class="inicio3 inicio4 inicio5">
  <a href="{{ route('instituto')}}" class="inicio4 inicio5">Instituto</a>
</li>
<li class="inicio3 inicio4 inicio5">
  <a href="#" class="inicio4 inicio5">Aulas</a>
</li>
<li class="inicio3 inicio4 inicio5">
  <a href="#" class="inicio4 inicio5">Departamentos</a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Creo que no esta muy bonito, pero al menos funciona.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: es lógico que esto ocurra porque estas aplicando estilos por etiquetas html y no por id o por un nombre de clase. Debes asignarle una clase o un id a los estilos y aplicarle estilos solo a ellos.

Comment: Debes aplicar los estilos ya sea por id (usando #) o crear clases especificas para los elementos de tu menú nada más, algo como `class = "nav-menu"` para que el css lo llames así `.nav-menu` y así no afectas a las etiquetas del HTML directamente

Comment: SI la respuesta que te han dado te ha servido deberías marcarla como aceptada. Si tienes una respuesta mejor deberías publicarla como respuesta y no añadirla en la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Realmente tu problema se centra en que estás aplicando los estilos a las etiquetas HTML pero no a los elementos concretos para los cuales quieres cambiar un estilo.

Para realizar lo que tu quieres necesitarás usar clases o ID's. Las clases se utilizan cuando quieres que más de un elemento tenga un mismo estilo y los ID cuando te quieras referir a un solo elemento.

**Ejemplo cambiando el color de texto por etiqueta HTML**:

```css
span{
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<span>Este es un texto rojo</span><br>
<span>Este es un texto rojo</span><br>
<span>Este es un texto rojo</span><br>
<span>Este es un texto rojo</span><br>
```

Como puedes observar, el estilo se aplica a todas las etiquetas `span`.

**Ejemplo cambiando el color de texto por clases e ID**

```css
.rojo{
   color: red;
}

#azul{
   color: blue;
}
```

```html
<span class="rojo">Este es un texto rojo</span><br>
<span class="rojo">Este es un texto rojo</span><br>
<span>Este es un texto por defecto</span><br>
<span id="azul">Este es un texto rojo</span><br>
```

Como puedes observar, en este caso he aplicado una clase llamada `rojo` a varios de los textos pero sin afectar al resto de elementos, solo los que tienen dicha clase.

Además, he utilizado un ID llamado `azul` que aplico a un solo elemento. **No apliques ID's iguales a más de un elemento, en su defecto usa clases**.

Ten en cuenta que el texto al que no le hemos indicado ninguna clase o ID no se ve afectado.

**NOTA:** En tu CSS los ID's se verán representados por una almohadilla `#` y las clases por un punto `.`